# Проблема с загрузкой Debian

Tags: debian, драйвер

Только что установил Debian, и решил поставить туда драйвера для своей видеокарты `Nvidia GeForce gtx 1050`. Использовал эту инструкцию: [http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/драйвер_видеокарт_nvidia](http://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82_nvidia), по этой инструкции собрал драйвер из исходников. После установки перезагрузил систему, и теперь вижу циклично повторяющееся сообщение:

```
Starting User Manager for UID 116
Started User Manager for UID 116
```

Вот не знаю теперь, как починить.

Comment: я кучу раз устанавливал Дебиан а всегда он дровишки цеплял автоматически ... без гемороя

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, он цепляет свободные драйвера, но у меня с ними есть проблема с производительностью.

Comment: @Andrey, теперь «проблема с производительностью» кардинально решилась! верно? ваш собственный опыт вам же и показывает, что не стоит запускать всякий шлак «от производителя». даже если маркетологи обещают вам «решение всех ваших проблем».